# Prove $1!+2!+3!+.....n!$ is never a square, for $n>4$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove $1!+2!+3!+.....n!$ is never a square, for $n>4$

Please help with this problem. I tried to do it by assuming it to be in the form of $4K + 3$ since if it is an odd non perfect square.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint**:

For each $k \geq 5$, $10 ~|~ k!$.

So, $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k! \equiv 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! \equiv 3 \pmod {10}. $$

And you know squares must end in one of $0,1,4,5,6,9$.